# DNN: How can I convert my existing HTML/CSS/JS website I designed on sublime text into DNN? (DNN 7.9.2)

Tags: dotnetnuke

I want to convert my site into DNN, I have three CSS files: main.css, slick.css, slick-theme.css and two js files: main.js, slick.min.js. In their particular folders named i.e. css, and js. And one img folder containing all the images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best solution is to include those files into a dnn skin (theme).

Either you install a minimal skin and you modify it to include them, either you could developp your own dnn skin.

If you developp a skin, the file main.css can be renamed skin.css to be automaticaly loaded by dnn.
I think that main difficulty will remain to create the layouts using dnn skin objects like the menu. You can look at the Xcillion skin to see an example. It uses the DDRMenu which is flexible component to design website menus.

Here are some links to help you:

- the official documentation for designers
  http://www.dnnsoftware.com/DOCS/designers/index.html
- an article with
  many links https://www.dnnsoftware.com/wiki/dotnetnuke-skins

Comment: Thanks! Will check this out.